# Service или Thread? Как организовать постоянное слежение за временем?

Tags: android, многопоточность

Пусть существует некое текстовое поле и некий временной интервал вида 12:00:00 - 23:00:00. В текстовое поле должно выводится либо `true`, либо `false` в зависимости от того, входит ли системное время(время которое отображается в данный момент в системе) в заданный интервал времени, причем эта информация должна проверяется все время. Сам алгоритм проверки вхождения времени во временной интервал не вызывает вопросов. Больше вопросов вызывает сама **постоянная** проверка времени.
Не знаю какими способами реализовать это, естественно это нужно реализовывать в отдельном потоке, только что использовать? Бесконечный `AsyncTask`, или `Thread`, или уже делать собственный `Service`, который будет постоянно мониторить текущее время, проверять на вхождение в интервал и если что отправлять данные в основной поток? Как лучше реализовать то, что я описал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html или http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html но поаккуратней со ссылкой на активити и отображение в элементе, который может быть уже уничтожен.